# In phonegap how to pass arguments in callback function via navigator.notification.alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```
function alertDismissed(tag_name) { // This is callback function
    tag_name.focus();
}

function showAlert(msg, callbackfn) {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'Please enter email',          // message
        alertDismissed:'callbackfn',   // callback
        'App name',                    // title
        'Ok'                           // buttonName
    );
}
```

I want to pass arguments to the `alertDismissed()` function. I am calling it like this:

```
UserName=document.getElementById("name-txt").value;
if(UserName == "" || UserName == null)
{
    showAlert("Please enter email","name-txt");
}
```

Actually, I want focus after clicking the "ok" button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
function showAlert(msg, callbackfn) {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'Please enter email',          // message
        function () {
           console.log(callbackfn);
        },   // callback
        'App name',                    // title
        'Ok'                           // buttonName
    );
}
```